# Как загрузить несколько изображений? django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Необходимо реализовать загрузку нескольких изображений, но выбрать несколько не получается (когда зажимаю ctrl). Как это исправить?

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    objects = ImageQuerySet.as_manager()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               null=True,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               verbose_name='Пользователь')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', verbose_name='Изображение')
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Кол-во просмотров')
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TAG_CHOICES, blank=True, verbose_name='Тэг')
```

**api.py**

```
class PostModelView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Просмотр/Создание/Редактирование/Удаление поста"""
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostsListSerializer
    permission_classes_by_action = {'update': [permissions.IsAdminUser],
                                    'destroy': [IsAuthorEntry]}

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
        for item in self.request.FILES.getlist('image'):
            Post.objects.create(image=item, author=self.request.user, tag=self.request.tag)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostsListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Список постов"""

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

        image = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField(required=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй промежуточную таблицу, по типу

```
class ImagePost(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', verbose_name='Изображение')

class Post(models.Model):
    objects = ImageQuerySet.as_manager()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               null=True,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               verbose_name='Пользователь')
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ImagePost)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Кол-во просмотров')
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TAG_CHOICES, blank=True, verbose_name='Тэг')
```

Тогда уже создаешь сеаризатор для создания изображения и в модель Post через сериализатор создания поста вносишь id изображений, в методе create сериализатора вносишь через

```
post=Post.objects.create(...) post.images.set(id) либо post.images.add(id)
```

Тут почитай про отношения сериализаторов